# How do I make a matrix from a list of vectors in R?

Tags: r, matrix, vector

Goal: from a list of vectors of equal length, create a matrix where each vector becomes a row.

Example:

```
> a <- list()
> for (i in 1:10) a[[i]] <- c(i,1:5)
> a
[[1]]
[1] 1 1 2 3 4 5

[[2]]
[1] 2 1 2 3 4 5

[[3]]
[1] 3 1 2 3 4 5

[[4]]
[1] 4 1 2 3 4 5

[[5]]
[1] 5 1 2 3 4 5

[[6]]
[1] 6 1 2 3 4 5

[[7]]
[1] 7 1 2 3 4 5

[[8]]
[1] 8 1 2 3 4 5

[[9]]
[1] 9 1 2 3 4 5

[[10]]
[1] 10  1  2  3  4  5
```

I want:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
 [1,]    1    1    2    3    4    5
 [2,]    2    1    2    3    4    5
 [3,]    3    1    2    3    4    5
 [4,]    4    1    2    3    4    5
 [5,]    5    1    2    3    4    5
 [6,]    6    1    2    3    4    5
 [7,]    7    1    2    3    4    5
 [8,]    8    1    2    3    4    5
 [9,]    9    1    2    3    4    5
[10,]   10    1    2    3    4    5
```

Answer (score 140, accepted):

One option is to use `do.call()`:

```
 > do.call(rbind, a)
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
 [1,]    1    1    2    3    4    5
 [2,]    2    1    2    3    4    5
 [3,]    3    1    2    3    4    5
 [4,]    4    1    2    3    4    5
 [5,]    5    1    2    3    4    5
 [6,]    6    1    2    3    4    5
 [7,]    7    1    2    3    4    5
 [8,]    8    1    2    3    4    5
 [9,]    9    1    2    3    4    5
[10,]   10    1    2    3    4    5
```

Comment: So the difference between this and the standard rbind() is that do.call() passes each list item as a separate arg - is that right?  do.call(rbind,a) is equivalent to rbind(a[[1]], a[[2]]... a[[10]])?

Comment: do.call() is great for this purpose, I wish it were better "documented" in the introductory materials.

Answer (score 21):

`simplify2array` is a base function that is fairly intuitive. However, since R's default is to fill in data by columns first, you will need to transpose the output. (`sapply` uses `simplify2array`, as documented in `help(sapply)`.)

```
> t(simplify2array(a))
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
 [1,]    1    1    2    3    4    5
 [2,]    2    1    2    3    4    5
 [3,]    3    1    2    3    4    5
 [4,]    4    1    2    3    4    5
 [5,]    5    1    2    3    4    5
 [6,]    6    1    2    3    4    5
 [7,]    7    1    2    3    4    5
 [8,]    8    1    2    3    4    5
 [9,]    9    1    2    3    4    5
[10,]   10    1    2    3    4    5
```

Answer (score 18):

The built-in `matrix` function has the nice option to enter data `byrow`. Combine that with an `unlist` on your source list will give you a matrix. We also need to specify the number of rows so it can break up the unlisted data. That is:

```
> matrix(unlist(a), byrow=TRUE, nrow=length(a) )
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
 [1,]    1    1    2    3    4    5
 [2,]    2    1    2    3    4    5
 [3,]    3    1    2    3    4    5
 [4,]    4    1    2    3    4    5
 [5,]    5    1    2    3    4    5
 [6,]    6    1    2    3    4    5
 [7,]    7    1    2    3    4    5
 [8,]    8    1    2    3    4    5
 [9,]    9    1    2    3    4    5
[10,]   10    1    2    3    4    5
```

Comment: Or fill a matrix by columns and then transpose: `t( matrix( unlist(a), ncol=length(a) ) )`.

Comment: this can be 7x faster than the `do.call(rbind,)`-approach for matrices with many rows, but sometimes won't warn if vectors don't have the same size.

Answer (score 12):

Not straightforward, but it works:

```
> t(sapply(a, unlist))
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
 [1,]    1    1    2    3    4    5
 [2,]    2    1    2    3    4    5
 [3,]    3    1    2    3    4    5
 [4,]    4    1    2    3    4    5
 [5,]    5    1    2    3    4    5
 [6,]    6    1    2    3    4    5
 [7,]    7    1    2    3    4    5
 [8,]    8    1    2    3    4    5
 [9,]    9    1    2    3    4    5
[10,]   10    1    2    3    4    5
```

Comment: With `rjson` results, `colMeans` works only for this method! Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

```
t(sapply(a, '[', 1:max(sapply(a, length))))
```

where 'a' is a list. 
Would work for unequal row size

Answer (score 3):

```
> library(plyr)
> as.matrix(ldply(a))
      V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6
 [1,]  1  1  2  3  4  5
 [2,]  2  1  2  3  4  5
 [3,]  3  1  2  3  4  5
 [4,]  4  1  2  3  4  5
 [5,]  5  1  2  3  4  5
 [6,]  6  1  2  3  4  5
 [7,]  7  1  2  3  4  5
 [8,]  8  1  2  3  4  5
 [9,]  9  1  2  3  4  5
[10,] 10  1  2  3  4  5
```

Comment: This will simply not work if the rows don't have the same length, while do.call(rbind,...) still works.

Comment: any clues how to make it work for unequal row size with NA for the missing row data?

Comment: @rwst Actually, do.call(rbind,...) does not work for unequal-length vectors, unless you really intend to have the vector reused when filling in the row at the end. See Arihant's response for a way that fills in with `NA` values at the end instead.

Answer (score -1):

`data.table::transpose(a)` can be a useful tool here if you your list elements have unequal size or you actually wanted a `data.frame` instead.

It efficiently turns a length-n list of length-up-to-p vectors into a length-p list of length-n vectors, padding the missing elements with a value of your choice.

```r
# For list of vectors of unequal size if you want to pad instead of recycle
a <- sapply(1:6, function(i) c(i, seq_len(i)))
a
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 1 1
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 2 1 2
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] 3 1 2 3
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1] 4 1 2 3 4
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> [1] 5 1 2 3 4 5
#> 
#> [[6]]
#> [1] 6 1 2 3 4 5 6

matrix(unlist(data.table::transpose(a)), nrow=length(a))
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
#> [1,]    1    1   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
#> [2,]    2    1    2   NA   NA   NA   NA
#> [3,]    3    1    2    3   NA   NA   NA
#> [4,]    4    1    2    3    4   NA   NA
#> [5,]    5    1    2    3    4    5   NA
#> [6,]    6    1    2    3    4    5    6
#
## neat if you want a data.frame instead
data.table::setDF(data.table::as.data.table(data.table::transpose(a)))[]
#>   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7
#> 1  1  1 NA NA NA NA NA
#> 2  2  1  2 NA NA NA NA
#> 3  3  1  2  3 NA NA NA
#> 4  4  1  2  3  4 NA NA
#> 5  5  1  2  3  4  5 NA
#> 6  6  1  2  3  4  5  6
```

It is almost as fast as the  `matrix(unlist(` `), byrow=TRUE)` solution and much faster than the `t(sapply(` approach that also works for unequal lengths.

```r
a <- sapply(1:6, function(i) c(i, seq_len(i)))
a
bench::mark(
  matrix(unlist(data.table::transpose(a)), nrow=length(a)),
  t(sapply(a, '[', 1:max(sapply(a, length))))
)
#> # A tibble: 2 × 6
#>   expression                                                      min   median
#>   <bch:expr>                                                 <bch:tm> <bch:tm>
#> 1 matrix(unlist(data.table::transpose(a)), nrow = length(a))   6.87µs   8.68µs
#> 2 t(sapply(a, "[", 1:max(sapply(a, length))))                 33.29µs  42.14µs
#> # ℹ 3 more variables: `itr/sec` <dbl>, mem_alloc <bch:byt>, `gc/sec` <dbl>



# small list, equal sizes
a <- sapply(1:6, function(i) c(i, seq_len(5)), simplify = FALSE)
a
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 1 1 2 3 4 5
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 2 1 2 3 4 5
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] 3 1 2 3 4 5
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1] 4 1 2 3 4 5
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> [1] 5 1 2 3 4 5
#> 
#> [[6]]
#> [1] 6 1 2 3 4 5

bench::mark(
  matrix(unlist(data.table::transpose(a)), nrow=length(a)),
  t(sapply(a, '[', 1:max(sapply(a, length)))),
  do.call(rbind, a),
  matrix(unlist(a), byrow=TRUE, nrow=length(a) )
)
#> # A tibble: 4 × 6
#>   expression                                                      min   median
#>   <bch:expr>                                                 <bch:tm> <bch:tm>
#> 1 matrix(unlist(data.table::transpose(a)), nrow = length(a))   7.03µs   9.06µs
#> 2 t(sapply(a, "[", 1:max(sapply(a, length))))                 32.99µs  36.18µs
#> 3 do.call(rbind, a)                                            2.92µs   3.47µs
#> 4 matrix(unlist(a), byrow = TRUE, nrow = length(a))            2.77µs   3.07µs
#> # ℹ 3 more variables: `itr/sec` <dbl>, mem_alloc <bch:byt>, `gc/sec` <dbl>


# large list, equal sizes
a <- sapply(seq_len(100000), function(i) c(i, seq_len(5)), simplify = FALSE)

bench::mark(
  matrix(unlist(data.table::transpose(a)), nrow=length(a)),
  t(sapply(a, '[', 1:max(sapply(a, length)))),
  do.call(rbind, a),
  matrix(unlist(a), byrow=TRUE, nrow=length(a) )
)
#> Warning: Some expressions had a GC in every iteration; so filtering is disabled.
#> # A tibble: 4 × 6
#>   expression                                                      min   median
#>   <bch:expr>                                                 <bch:tm> <bch:tm>
#> 1 matrix(unlist(data.table::transpose(a)), nrow = length(a))  11.62ms  12.54ms
#> 2 t(sapply(a, "[", 1:max(sapply(a, length))))                 94.56ms 101.09ms
#> 3 do.call(rbind, a)                                           59.02ms  70.49ms
#> 4 matrix(unlist(a), byrow = TRUE, nrow = length(a))            7.02ms   7.82ms
#> # ℹ 3 more variables: `itr/sec` <dbl>, mem_alloc <bch:byt>, `gc/sec` <dbl>
```