# KNN with multidimensional vectors

Tags: r, machine-learning, knn

Let me give some background context: I have a list of 100 vectors, each one with 50 dimensions, and I'd like to associate the first 50 vectors with class A and the last ones with class B.

My question is: How can I do it in order to apply kNN later and which library has a kNN method more appropriate for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the first options that come to my mind is to make a data.frame from a list of vectors, create factor indicator and then use knn from [class package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/class/index.html).

**Make a data.frame from a list of vectors**

Using rbind, make a matrix and then use as.data.frame function (more examples in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329940/how-do-i-make-a-matrix-from-a-list-of-vectors-in-r)). Assuming that l is a list of vectors:

```
data <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, l))
```

**Factor indicator**

```
class <- as.factor(c(rep("A", 50), rep("B", 50)))
```

**kNN classification using class package**

In case you don't have separate data for testing, probably the best way would be

```
train.ind <- sample(1:100, 75) # making indexes to split data into 75% train and 25% test
resulting.classes <- knn(train = data[train.ind, ], test = data[-train.ind, ], cl = class)
```

And if you have separate train and test data then just use

```
resulting.classes <- knn(train = train.data, test = test.data, cl = class)
```

Other choices for kNN that might be useful - [‘kknn’ package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kknn/) and ['FNN' package.](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/FNN/), but class package seems the easiest one for simple kNN classification.