# I would like to fill a matrix with values of a list

Tags: r, list, matrix

I have a list of 6 with 10 values in each. I would like to fill a 10x6 (10 rows, 6 columns) matrix with these values. I've tried some things but it's not working. I'm sure there must be an easy way to do it, but I haven't found it yet. Could anyone please help?

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329940/how-do-i-make-a-matrix-from-a-list-of-vectors-in-r

Answer (score 1):

Here some example data:

```
l = lapply(1:6, rep, 10)
```

then use `?do.call` and `cbind` to paste the list elements as columns:

```
do.call(cbind, l)
```

and you get a matrix:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
 [1,]    1    2    3    4    5    6
 [2,]    1    2    3    4    5    6
 [3,]    1    2    3    4    5    6
 [4,]    1    2    3    4    5    6
 [5,]    1    2    3    4    5    6
 [6,]    1    2    3    4    5    6
 [7,]    1    2    3    4    5    6
 [8,]    1    2    3    4    5    6
 [9,]    1    2    3    4    5    6
[10,]    1    2    3    4    5    6
```